# Use ForeignKey model's attributes in another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

In django I have two models like this:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(foo)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to set default of `bar.number` to `foo.number`. How can I do it in django?
When I use `default = foo.number` I get `Cannot access member "number" for type "ForeignKey"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(foo)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.number is None:
            self.number = self.foo.number
        super(bar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

or, to use foo.number as default only on the first save (object creation):

```
 class bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(foo)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and self.number is None:
            self.number = self.foo.number
        super(bar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I want to set each bar model's number to its ForeignKey's number. If I use function `save` should not I run the function for each bar model to do this? Can I add `save`'s contents to `__init__` function?

Comment: save() is ran by Django by default

Comment: So do we need to use `super` if django runs `save` automatically? Sorry I am new to django.

Comment: yes we do need to use super(), for the model to do whatever the parent does after modifying the data

Answer (score 0):

You can archive those things using **`pre_save`** signal like this...

#### models.py

```py
class foo(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.number}"

class bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(foo,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.number}"


@receiver(pre_save, sender=bar)
def add_foo_number(instance, sender, **kwargs):
    is_exist_foo = foo.objects.filter(number=instance.number).exists() 
    if not is_exist_foo:
        f= foo.objects.create(number=instance.number)
        instance.foo = f
```

#### admin.py

```py
@admin.register(foo)
class fooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("number",)


@admin.register(bar)
class barAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("number", "foo")
```

#### Browser output

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am new to django. In this way, Foo's number should be unique?

Comment: you want foos number unique ??

Comment: In this case yes, but if I find a way for any cases like this will be better.

Comment: if i create *101* second time in ```bar``` model then in ```foo``` model *101* not create

Comment: it means you can create 101 in ```bar``` model but in ```foo``` only one time

Comment: How can I prevent to create a new Foo if a Foo with the `number` does not exist?

Comment: your mean if Foo exist then prevent to same Foo creation ??

Comment: i mean if foo already exist with 101 number then prevent to new creation with 101 for foo

Comment: No. I say is `foo` 101 exists, `number` of `bar` 101 sets to `foo` 101's number, but if there is no `foo` 101, prevent from creating `bar` 101 not to create a `foo` 101.

Comment: code updated plz check it, also check output image

Comment: In my code, multiple `bar`s can have same `number`, but `number` of each `foo` is different than others and unique.